# Iterate Over XML Response With ElementTreee Django

Tags: python, xml, django

My goal is to take the xml response and save it to my database. I was able to access the first element with `Elementtree` which was `products`

The xml looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <item id="0">
        <product_id>  ...
        <product_name> ...
        <product_url> ...
        <advertiser> ...
        <designer> ...
        <image_url> ...
        <price> ...
        <commission> ... 
    </item>
```

When I try and iterate over it I get the element but not the data in the element printed out for each element.

```
def advertisers(request):
    url = 'https://api.example.com/111'
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    tree = ElementTree.parse(response.raw)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for item in root:
        product_id =  item.find('product_id')
        product_name = item.find('product_name')
        product_url = item.find('product_url')
        advertiser = item.find('advertiser')
        designer = item.find('designer')
        image_url = item.find('image_url')
        price = item.find('price')
        commission = item.find('commission')
    print (product_id, product_name, product_url, advertiser, designer, image_url, price, commission)
    return HttpResponse()

Output
<Element 'product_id' at 0x107bba6d8> <Element 'product_name' at 0x107bba728> <Element 'product_url' at 0x107bba778> <Element 'advertiser' at 0x107bba7c8> <Element 'designer' at 0x107bba818> <Element 'image_url' at 0x107bba868> <Element 'price' at 0x107bba8b8> <Element 'commission' at 0x107bba908>
```

If my model looks like this, would someone please show me how to structure this loop to save the elements to the database. I know if I loop through them and append each set I can call `items.save()` and all should be well. I just want to make sure I am accessing the correctly first.

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    advertiser = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commission = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.products
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you can get an element value through `text` property like `product_id.text`, `product_name.text`, so on. Is that what you're asking now (after the edit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse), `iterparse()` returns `(event, elem)` pairs (notice the order). Your code has `event` and `elem` variables in the wrong order, that's why it always print `end` from "end" `event`. Correct the ordering, then you can check current element name from `elem.tag` and get value of the element from `elem.text` :

```
for event, elem in items:
    print(elem.tag, elem.text)
```

Comment: Yes thank you your original post helped me a lot. I went to answer it and it went away. lol I am sorry I edited it.