# Iterating ElementTree In Python Django

Tags: python, django

I have xml inside of ElementTree. I am trying to find the best way to iterate through the data and save it to a database. currently I am using `iterparse`
But I have only been able to print one element at a time then go back through to the beginning and start on the next.

How can I assign the elements to variables so I can handle the data to my database?

```
def advertisers(request):
    url = 'https://api.example.com/apikey'
    xml = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    tree = ElementTree.iterparse(xml.raw)
    print('about to save to database')
    for products, item in tree:
   #   Handl Data Here
   #   Save to database
   return HttpResponse()
```

This is how I am creating my model but cannot figure out how to access the data in the response.

```
Product.objects.create(product_id=?, product_name=?, product_url=?, advertiser=?, designer=?, image_url=?, price=?, commission=item.text)
```

Comment: Could you show an example XML sample that you are trying to parse? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this earlier, and i guess this is your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243129/iterate-over-xml-response-with-elementtreee-django):

```
<item id="0">
    <product_id>  ...
    <product_name> ...
    <product_url> ...
    <advertiser> ...
    <designer> ...
    <image_url> ...
    <price> ...
    <commission> ... 
</item>
```

Based on the xml, try this:

```
for item in tree.iter('item'):
    product_id =  item.find('product_id').text
    product_name = item.find('product_name').text
    product_url = item.find('product_url').text
    advertiser = item.find('advertiser').text
    designer = item.find('designer').text
    image_url = item.find('image_url').text
    price = item.find('price').text
    commission = item.find('commission').text
    product_to_save = Product.objects.create(product_id=product_id, product_name=product_name, product_url=product_url, advertiser=advertiser, designer=designer, image_url=image_url, price=price, commission=commission)
    product_to_save.save()
```

I haven't tested it, but pretty much should work.

Comment: Thank you. I was so close by the end. I could not find that anywhere? Do you have a link to where it talks about accessing the tree? That worked but it would be nice to read it.

Comment: Super, I suggest this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for more info.